# Need to put a text diagonally in box. using Css

Tags: javascript, css, birt

[image: Diagonally placed text in Box]

Hi can this be achieved using Css or Javascript?
need this for a Birt report.

Comment: its a corporate environment , we are using IE8

Comment: can anybody see the image I uploaded , I could not see .

Comment: Your image with words diagonally over 5 boxes is visible.

Comment: Are the words static, or do they very at report run time?  If they very how many options are there?

Comment: words are static, but this is for a BIRT report.

Comment: Instead of using text, you can use an image; much like the one you posted as an example.  If you sometimes need 3 of the 5, make each word/box combination a separate image.  You can use a grid inside of a grid if needed to organize the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers are irrelevant because they do not take into consideration this question is in a BIRT context. Short answer is this feature is not natively supported in BIRT. You can do this for labels in charts, but not for other elements such Data, Dynamic text etc.

You could include a css file at view time, and make use of a css rule in a text element declared as "HTML" type, but it is complicated to maintain and this would only work with html outputs: other formats such PDF and Excel would not take css rules into consideration.

Your best option is to make use of this Eclipse project [BIRT control libs](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/birt-controls-lib/) which extends BIRT in particular with a "diagonal text" control.

Answer (score 4):

**CSS:**

```
.lbl{
     width: 80px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: -22px;
    transform:rotate(-50deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-50deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(-50deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */}
.inp {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type='checkbox' id='cb1' class='inp'>
<div class='lbl'><label for='cb1'>first</label></div>

<input type='checkbox' id='cb2' class='inp'>
<div class='lbl'><label for='cb2'>second</label></div>

<input type='checkbox' id='cb3' class='inp'>
<div class='lbl'><label for='cb3'>third</label></div>

<input type='checkbox' id='cb4' class='inp'>
<div class='lbl'><label for='cb4'>fourth</label></div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE-DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/HT7JY/)

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
.diagonal {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
     -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
       -o-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.7071067811865482, M12=0.7071067811865466, M21=-0.7071067811865466, M22=0.7071067811865482, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.7071067811865482, M12=0.7071067811865466, M21=-0.7071067811865466, M22=0.7071067811865482, SizingMethod='auto expand');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/XqC95/1/)

Answer (score 2):

u can simply use `transform:rotate(x);`

```
transform:rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can define a CSS class with property `transform: rotate();` and assign to the the elements that you need to be affected.

check this example in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)

to rotate the text from a specific angle

Answer (score 1):

You can use Css property `transform: rotate();` to achieve this.